# How often has the Pope asked all Catholics to pray the Rosary?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, rosary

In the history of the Catholic Church, I know there's been extra days of fasting and prayer called for by the Pope and Bishops, but other than prior to the Battle of Lepanto and [today (March 19th 2020, The Solemnity of St. Joseph) at 9:00 PM Rome Time](https://zenit.org/articles/this-feast-of-st-joseph-join-pope-francis-praying-rosary-at-9pm-rome-time/). Has the Pope ever asked all Catholics to pray the Rosary in unity (or as simultaneously as possible prior to mass communication and computerized synchronization)?

Comment: I think the phrase “in unity” or something along those lines would be better than “simultaneously”.

Comment: @KenGraham good point, simultaneous prayer isn't even possible over skype

Comment: Several encyclicals from at least Leo XIII onward have promoted the rosary; cf. William's [_The Rosary: Its History and Meaning_ pp. 137](https://archive.org/details/TheRosaryItsHistoryAndMeaning/page/n71/mode/2up)-46.